# Changing CSS properties using jQuery for a markup and different CSS files

Tags: jquery, css

I've a HTML markup and I've several CSS files with different properties assigned for the HTML elements which will act as the theme of the markup. Say the Markup is something like

```
<div id=main>
    <div>{More HTML elements, divs, spans etc}</div>
    <div>{More HTML elements, divs, spans etc}</div>
</div>
```

And the css is like

```
/*first.css*/
#main{
    someProperty: values;
}

#main div, #main ul li {
    someProperty: values;
}
```

Another css file

```
/*second.css*/
#main{
    someProperty: some other values;
}

#main div, #main ul li {
    someProperty: some other values;
}
```

There are more css files with different properties and values.

What I want to do is, at the click of a button, I want to change the CSS of the markup without changing the markup. So it will be something like

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    var file = $(this).attr('id');
    //remove the previous css file
    //add the new css file (filename is the js var file+'.css')
});
```

I cannot keep doing `$('#someId').css({ /* properties */});` as there are many properties in the CSS file.

So how do I best handle this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you can have single css with different properties you want to have in different classes. Whenever you want to change something. Just remove the current class using [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) and add the new class using [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).

In case you want to switch the css files . Have a look [here](http://www.jquery4u.com/dynamic-css-2/jquery-change-css-file-2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily remove `link` elements from the `head` with jQuery, they are treated as any other HTML element.

You can remove a certain CSS file from the document using:

```
$('link[href="fos.css"]').remove();
```

And then you can add another into the `head`:

```
var newCss='fos2.css';
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+newCss+'">');
```

or if you want to play nice:

```
var newCss='fos2.css';
$('<link>')
    .attr({
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        type: 'text/css',
        href: newCss
    })
    .appendTo('head');
```

I've created a [simple jsFiddle test case](http://jsfiddle.net/8HmRH/) for you.

Answer (score 0):

Keep information about layout independent of the color, images etc.If possible, create one css styling for body tag which has information of color in it.